# Trouble Installing libxp6 and multi-arch-support

Tags: package-management, software-installation, 20.04

I am following [this](https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya/learn-explore/caas/simplecontent/content/installing-maya-2020-ubuntu.html) guide, but I have run into some difficulties at step 11. When I type

```
sudo apt-get install ./libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb
```

I get

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'libxp6' instead of './libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libxp6 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

libxp6 and multiarch-support are what seem to be giving me difficulties. Searching on the web has given me [a little](https://pkgs.org/download/libxp6), but not enough to install. Even [the Ubuntu package website](https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libxp6) isn't helping.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then you have to install `multiarch-support` package [from 18.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/multiarch-support) first with

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./multiarch-support_2.27-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

and continue to follow the guide.

Comment: In step 12 where it says "sudo updated" is that a typo? The response I am getting is "sudo: updated: command not found" Deleting the d gives the same thing.

Comment: The `sudo updated` maybe a typo. Do not know what they really mean.

Answer (score 2):

`multiarch-support` only installs some docs/copyright files

You can ignore the dependency:

```
sudo dpkg --ignore-depends=multiarch-support  -i ./libxp6_1.0.2-2_amd64.deb
```